# Deploying LLM on Sagemaker Endpoint - CUDA out of Memory

Tags: gpu, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint, large-language-model, llama

I am trying to deploy LLM to Sagemaker Endpoint using custom scripts and I am facing an error :
CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 20.00 MiB. GPU 1 has a total capacty of 22.20 GiB of which 13.12 MiB is free. Process 13234 has 2.25 GiB memory in use. Process 13238 has 3.82 GiB memory in use. Process 13236 has 8.06 GiB memory in use. Process 13239 has 8.06 GiB memory in use. Of the allocated memory 6.93 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 49.59 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF : 400

**The thing is I was able to get a response for a couple of pings and then I started getting this error. I am clearing the cache in my predict function but I cannot understand 3 things:

1. Why I am getting this error after couple of successful response from Endpoint?
2. What and Why are the four processes eating space?
3. And obvious, How can I resolve this error?**

Comment: What model are you trying to deploy? Have you tested your container and scripts locally (say on ec2) and confirm you do not receive any issues?

Comment: Model: https://github.com/defog-ai/sqlcoder/blob/main/README.md or https://huggingface.co/defog/sqlcoder-7b-2/tree/main

Comment: I just confirmed the model scripts in Sagemaker notebooks (with GPU) and deployed it as Sagemaker endpoint: I was able to get couple of responses (predictions) from the deployed endpoint (with GPU). The third request gave me this error. For smaller GPU, I get this error on the first request itself.

Comment: Image used is 763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/huggingface-pytorch-inference:2.1.0-transformers4.37.0-gpu-py310-cu118-ubuntu20.04

Comment: W.r.t. what you mentioned about testing container and scripts locally using EC2, won't it be similar to deployment to endpoint? Asking this to acquire additional knowledge from you.

Comment: Correct and locally testing will allow you to debug the issue